# How to create project in BigQuery using api and not from UI

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are an ETL platform. We want to create a project on behalf of the user and provide access to them.
Is there a way to programmatically create the project under my account, and give access to the user(I have user's email Id)? Also, how to link a billing account to the project programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Creating a Project**

As you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#gcloud), you can create a new project by running one of the commands below:

- To create a new project

  ```
  gcloud projects create PROJECT_ID
  ```
- To create a new project inside a given organization

  ```
  gcloud projects create PROJECT_ID --organization=ORGANIZATION_ID
  ```
- To create a new project inside a given folder

  ```
  gcloud projects create PROJECT_ID --folder=FOLDER_ID
  ```

**Granting Access**

It's possible to grant access to a project using the `gcloud` command as well as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#granting-gcloud-manual). If you only need to add a new role, you can run:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <my-project> --member=user:my-user@example.com --role=<role_name>
```

**Linking billing account**

This is also possible using `gcloud` command in beta version as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/billing/projects/link). The command is:

```
gcloud beta billing projects link <PROJECT_ID> --billing-account=<BILLING_ACCOUNT_ID>
```

Comment: What is the default number of project which can be created? I can see, there is an option to request more quota, but can't find the default number of projects that can be created.

Comment: @Talha the default number is 25 projects

Comment: I have not created any project yet, but when I do try to create one, it says "you've 12 more projects remaining in your quota"
are you sure, it's 25 and is it documented somewhere?

Comment: @Talha the base value is 25 but sometimes it may vary. If you need to know more about it, I suggest that you contact google